# How to break for loop at the end of a line

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, io

Task at hand here is to create a dictionary using specified inputs.

First element is key and following elements are values.

Input:

```
name, George Mason
pa, 100.0, 100.0, 95.0, 95.0, 97.0
lab, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 0.0, 100.0
zy, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0
mid1, 90.0
mid2, 80.0
final, 85.0
```

Expected output, if project = False:

```
{'name': 'George Mason',
 'pa': [100.0, 100.0, 95.0, 95.0, 97.0],
 'lab': [100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 0.0, 100.0],
 'zy': [100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0],
 'mid1': 90.0, 'mid2': 80.0, 'final': 85.0}
```

Expected output, if project = True:

```
{'name': 'George Mason',
 'pa': [100.0, 100.0, 95.0, 95.0, 97.0, 97.4, 97.4, 97.4, 97.4],
 'lab': [100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 0.0, 100.0, 80.0, 80.0, 80.0, 80.0,
80.0, 80.0],
 'zy': [100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0,
100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0],
 'mid1': 90.0, 'mid2': 80.0, 'final': 85.0}
```

*"If project is True and there are fewer than 9
programming assignments, 11 labs, or 15 zyBooks, you will need to project values for
all of the missing grades (you do not need to consider the case where there are more
grades). To do this for a given assignment type, compute the average grade for that
assignment type, and then add copies of that average to the end of the given grade
values so that that assignment type has the correct number of grades. For example, if
the file had the following line "pa, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0", then
there are only 7 programming assignment grade values. If project were True, you
would compute the average of the given grades ((1.0+2.0+3.0+4.0+5.0+6.0+7.0)/7 =
4.0), and add that to the end of the list of grade values, so that the dictionary's value for
the key "pa" would be the list [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 4.0,
4.0]."*

**I haven't even reached the True section. Right now I am trying to figure out how to get rid of the KeyError: ('name', 'Carl F. Gauss\n'). I am assuming that it is because the code doesn't know to move on to the next line once it reaches the end of the first. How would I do that?**

**My code is currently:**

```
def read_grades_file(filename, project=False):
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    grade_dict = {}
    if project == False:
        for line in file.readlines():
            values = [line.split(', ')]
            key = tuple(values[0])
            val = values[1:]
            grade_dict[key].append(val)
    if project == True:
        for line in file.readlines():
            values = [line.split(', ')]
            key = tuple(values[0])
            val = values[1:]
    return grade_dict
        
print(read_grades_file('gauss.grades', project=False))
```

Comment: Use `line.strip()`

Comment: @Timus it then has the same error except this time it splits it up by character

Comment: You should do `values = line.split(“, “)`, not `values = […]`

Comment: And you don’t need to wrap the `key` into a `tuple()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a suggestion for the first part (which is the basis for the second):

```
def read_grades_file(filename, project=False):
    grade_dict = {}
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            key, *values = line.strip().split(', ')
            if key in {'pa', 'lab', 'zy'}:
                grade_dict[key] = list(map(float, values))
            else:
                value = values[0]
                if key in {'mid1', 'mid2', 'final'}:
                    value = float(value)
                grade_dict[key] = value
    if project:
        pass
    return grade_dict
```

Iterating through the lines of the file

- `.strip()` the `line` to get rid of whitespace, especially at the end (`'\n'`)
- `.split(', ')` it and unpack the resulting list in its first item `key` and the remaining items `values`
- if the key is `pa`, `lab`, or `zy` convert `values` into a list of floats and assign it to `key`
- otherwise extact the remaining item of `values` into the variable `value`, convert it into float if `key` is `mid1`, `mid2`, or `final`, and assign it to `key`.

Result for input

```
name, George Mason
pa, 100.0, 100.0, 95.0, 95.0, 97.0
lab, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 0.0, 100.0
zy, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0
mid1, 90.0
mid2, 80.0
final, 85.0
```

is

```
{'name': 'George Mason',
 'pa': [100.0, 100.0, 95.0, 95.0, 97.0],
 'lab': [100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 0.0, 100.0],
 'zy': [100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0],
 'mid1': 90.0,
 'mid2': 80.0,
 'final': 85.0}
```

Regarding the second part: Check if the lists have the required minimum length. If not, calculate the average of the present items (e.g. use `sum`, `math.fsum`, or `statistics.mean`) and `.extend()` the lists with the average to meet the minimum length requirement. (Let me know if you need help.)